# How can lightsabers have crossguards without an imperfect crystal?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, star-wars-rebels

If you haven't watched it yet, check out the latest trailer for [Star Wars Rebels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-eWFDyi5Ow), just a few days old.

You will notice a very familiar lightsaber design we once thought impossible and/or useless. But here it is again. In TFA, though, the "crossguards" on Kylo Ren's lightsaber were actually heat exhausts from an imperfect crystal first, *then* improvised as crossguards. The imperfect crystal couldn't channel all the energy into the main blade. In this new appearance, though, it appears they are truly just crossguards.

- Can actual crossguards be achieved using normal crystals?
- If it's a normal crystal, how is it done?
- If it's not normal crystals, are those also fractured crystals?
- If it's a fractured crystal, how is its blade's appearance more stable than Kylo's?

Comment: “the "crossguards" on Kylo Ren's lightsaber were actually heat exhausts from an imperfect crystal” — oh really? I didn’t know that.

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't simply have a two smaller crystals on either side of the main crystal. Pure speculation, though.

Answer (score 6):

Looking over the (vastly more sophisticated) lightsaber designs in the [Star Wars: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary), it struck me that more than one kyber crystal would be largely unnecessary since the most obvious place to split the energy would be within the "***energy channel***" itself. You could then focus that energy onto two or more "***blade emitters***" before it left the handle.

**Luke's Lightsaber**
[image]

**Luke's Lightsaber with added crossguards**
[image]

This would also explain Ren's lightsaber looks so ragged. The energy from the crystal isn't being channeled or modulated, it's just being dumped raw into the emitter

Answer (score 2):

There could be more than one crystal inside. The handles are also customized by the maker, so I image you could make it any shape.